# Doctrine 2, count when left join

Tags: doctrine-orm

I have this:

```
->select('COUNT(x)')->setMaxResults(null)->setFirstResult(0)->getQuery()->getSingleScalarResult();
```

this works as long as I dont have join. If I have left join, it will also count the duplicated left-columns. How to prevent that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by grouping:

```
$qb->select('COUNT(x)')
   ->leftJoin('x.another_table', 'a')
   ->groupBy('x.id')
   ->setMaxResults(null)
   ->setFirstResult(0)
   ->getQuery()
   ->getSingleScalarResult();
```

Comment: if I do this: "select('COUNT(DISTINCT x.id)')->setMaxResults(null)->setFirstResult(0)->getQuery()->getSingleScalarResult();" seems to work

Comment: It's kind of hard to write query, if you not provide schema and expected result ;-) That query is estimated…

Comment: whoops, I see. Anyway, my solution seems to be OK, at least on 5.7.11