# Doctrine count joined, grouped select

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I am trying to get count of rows of select with multiple joins that is grouped (same problem as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36296138/doctrine-2-count-when-left-join) but mentioned answer is not fully suitable).

I have code like this:

```
$this->createQueryBuilder('table1')
     ->select('count(table1.id)')
     ->leftJoin('table1.col1', 'table2')
     ->leftJoin('table1.col2', 'table3')
     ->leftJoin('table1.col3', 'table4')
     ->groupBy('table1.id')
     ->getQuery()
     ->getScalarResult();
```

As a result i have array like:

```
[
   ["1" => "1"],
   ["1" => "2"],
   ["1" => "1"],
   ["1" => "3"],
   ["1" => "3"],
   ...
]
```

But i need number of rows of result array.

Is it possible to do it in single query?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using  getSingleScalarResult()?

Comment: Error occurred when using getSingleScalarResult: "The query returned multiple rows. Change the query or use a different result function like getScalarResult()."